# Decorator not applying render function to protoype of class in meteor + react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, decorator

I have a `decorator` that applies a render function to the prototype of a react component, however, when I run the app in the browser I get the following error.

`Warning: App(...): No 'render' method found on the returned component instance: you may have forgotten to define 'render'.`

Here is the decorator code

```js
export function App(setup) {
    return function(target) {
        target.prototype.render = () => (
           <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme(setup.config.theme)}>
               <IntlProvider locale={setup.config.locale}>
                   <Provider
                       store={setup.config.state.store ?
                       setup.config.state.store
                       :
                       initializeRedux(setup.config.state.reducers, setup.config.state.initialState)}
          >
                       <Router>
                           <div>
                               {setup.pages.map((page, i) =>
                                   <Route key={i} {...page} />
                                )}
                                {setup.render ? setup.render() : ""}
                            </div>
                        </Router>
                    </Provider>
                </IntlProvider>
            </MuiThemeProvider>
        )
        return target;
    }
}
```

And the react component

```js
@DimApp({
    pages: [
        { path: '/', component: HomePage, children: [] }
    ],
    config: {
        theme,
        locale: 'en',
        state: {
          store
        }
    }
})
export default class App extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely you did not include the appropriate babel plugin (`babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy`).

In order to enable it, you should install the package and add it to your configuration:

```sh
meteor npm i -S babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy
```

and add it to your `package.json` or `.babelrc`,

```js
{
  "plugins": ["babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy"]
}
```

also indicated in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/6057#issuecomment-228532425).

Comment: Thanks, this was the issue. I would have thought decorators would have been enabled by default in meteor. Guess not :)